# Open Bootstrap Accordion and scroll to selected field MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open an accordion, then scroll to a selected field, which works fine if the accordion is open, otherwise it scrolls to the top of the accordion not the field.

I have left out the definitions, but this is the relevant bit of JavaScript that is released

```
 If Not vTelephone.Length = 12 Then
                SB.Append("PhoneLabel.innerHTML = 'Error - Phone is not valid! (123-456-7890)'; ")
                SB.Append("PhoneDiv.className = 'form-group has-error'; ")
                SB.Append("PhoneTB.focus(); ")
                SB.Append("$('#CompanyDetails').collapse('show'); ")
                SB.Append("PhoneTB.scrollIntoView(false); ")
                SB.Append("});")
                Return SB.ToString
            End If
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If the field is invisible, what should the page scroll to? Maybe you need to wait for the animation to finish before scrolling? Is that what you mean?

Comment: use the events api for `collapse()` to do it

Comment: The field is not invisible other than it is wrapped in an Accordion - so none of the fields can be seen until the Accordion is opened

Comment: charlieftl - can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I set a timeout (to allow the textbox to be visible), but seems rather hacky..

```
 If Not vTelephone.Length = 12 Then
                SB.Append("$('#CompanyDetails').collapse('show'); ")
                SB.Append("PhoneLabel.innerHTML = 'Error - Phone is not valid! (123-456-7890)'; ")
                SB.Append("PhoneDiv.className = 'form-group has-error'; ")

                SB.Append("setTimeout(function(){ ")

                SB.Append("PhoneTB.focus(); ")
                SB.Append("PhoneTB.scrollIntoView(false); ")

                SB.Append("}, 1000); ")


                SB.Append("});")
                Return SB.ToString
            End If
```